# jquery tooltip and list from db with php

Tags: php, tooltip

hello i use a easytooltip jquery script and i list somw table from my database like this:

```
<style>
#easyTooltip{
background: #000000;
    width:250px;
    line-height:130%;   
color: #ffffff; 
    }
#easyTooltip p{
    margin:0 0 .5em 0;
    }       
#easyTooltip img{
        padding:1px;
        float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
        }       

#optiuni{display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easyTooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("a#link").easyTooltip({
            useElement: "optiuni"                  
        });
    });
</script>
<div id='item_catalog'>
<table>
<tr>
<td><a id='link'>< img src /template/ezra/images/items_info/$row[12].png ></a></td>
<td>
<div  id='optiuni'><table align='center'>
<tr>
<td align='center'><span class='text1'>Excellent $row[1] $type</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='center'><span class='text2'>$def_pwr $row[2]</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='center'><span class='text3'>Durability: [$row[4]/$row[4]]</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='center'><span class='text3'>Speed: $row[3]</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  align='center'><span class='text3'>Level Requirement: $row[5]</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  align='center'><span class='text3'>Strenght Requirement: $row[6]</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  align='center'><span class='text3'>Agility Requirement: $row[7]</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  align='center'><span class='text3'>Vitality Requirement: $row[8]</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  align='center'><span class='text3'>Energy Requirement: $row[9]</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  align='center'><span class='text3'>Command Requirement: $row[10]</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='background:#a00000;' align='center'><span class='text3'>Class Requirement: $clasa</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='center'><span class='text4'>$opt</span></td>
</tr>
</table></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

but i have some problem tooltip appear only for 1st row:( second 3 row no have tooltip, why? how can i dot to show tooltip for every image list from my database?

Answer (score 0):

You told the plugin to create the tooltip for every `$("a#link")`. But there is only one element with this id. (You cant't have multiple elements with the same id)

Try it with a class selector. Example: `$('.text3')`

Updated answer:
change `<div id='optiuni'>` to `<div class="tooltip-content">`
change `<a id='link'>` to `<a class='link'>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.link').each(function(){
        var that = $(this);
        that.easyTooltip({
            content: that.parent().parent().find('.tooltip-content').html()                  
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: yes thx this work but now i have a problem with php, when hover on every image show same stats, but in my db each image have different stats, how to modify my php sript?

Comment: $query = mssql_query("Select type,name,defense,speed,durability,level_req,str_req,agi_req,vit_req,ene_req,cmd_req,class,imagine from ITEM_INFO where class='$clasa' AND type='5'");

for($i=0;$i < mssql_num_rows($query);++$i)
{
$row = mssql_fetch_row($query);
 and rest is up code